# VSTS Task Groups: use variable in task title

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

(I'm using hosted VSTS.)

I have written a generic database deployment Task Group, and I would like the title to include the name of the database being provisioned.
E.g.: `Deploy schema $(databaseName)`
When I run an instance of the task, though, the variable substitution doesn't happen.

Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

### Steps to reproduce

- Create a task group named "Provision database"
- Add a task of type Azure SQL Database Deployment
- Set the name of said task to `Deploy schema $(databaseName)`
- Create a Release which includes said task
- Run the release
- In the release log the task appears as:

  `##[section]Starting: Deploy schema $(databaseName)`

The problem being that the databaseName variable is not replaced with its value.

Below is a screenshot of the relevant Azure SQL Database Deployment configuration
[image: Azure SQL Database Deployment configuration]

Comment: What're steps to reproduce this issue? I can use variable in the task name of Task Group.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I've included steps to reproduce in the original question, thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Can you reproduce this issue with a new release definition and new task group? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive?

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I have time at the moment. A note though: the task that is showing the problem is part of a task group which is included in another task group.

Provision all dbs TG --> Provision DB TG --> Azure Task

I'll (re)try to reproduce asap.

Comment: I still can't reproduce this issue. What's the version of your agent? (Agent.Version of agent capabilities)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have access to the system any more. Thanks for looking into it though.

Comment: What do you mean you don' have access to the system? You can check it in agent pool page `https://[account].visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool`

Comment: It was a client system, for which my contract has now expired, and my credentials have thus been revoked.
I need to reproduce the issue with my personal account, if I have time.

Comment: You can delete this thread and open a new thread if you meet the issue again.